# Elasticsearch highlight matches in HTML without breaking syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

Elasticsearch has a built-in "highlight" function which allows you to tag the matched terms in the results (more complicated than it might at first sound, since the query syntax can include near matches etc.).

I have HTML fields, and Elasticsearch stomps all over the HTML syntax when I turn on highlighting.

Can I make it HTML-aware / HTML-safe when highlighting in this way?

I'd like the highlighting to apply to the text in the HTML document, and not to highlight any HTML markup which has matched the search, i.e. a search for "p" might highlight `<p>p</p>` -> `<p><mark>p</mark></p>`.

My fields are indexed as "`type: string`".

The [documentation says](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-highlighting.html#_encoder):

> Encoder:
>
> An encoder parameter can be used to define how highlighted
>   text will be encoded. It can be either default (no encoding) or html
>   (will escape html, if you use html highlighting tags).

.. but that HTML-escapes my already HTML-encoded field, breaking things further.

Here are two example queries

1. Using the default encoder:

The highlight tags are inserted inside other tags, i.e. `<p>` -> `<<tag1>p</tag1>>`:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-type: application/json' "http://localhost:7200/myindex/_search?pretty" -d '
{
  "query": { "match": { "preview_html": "p" } },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags" : ["<tag1>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</tag1>"],
    "encoder": "default",
    "fields": {
      "preview_html" : {}
    }
  },
  "from" : 22, "size" : 1
}'

GIVES:
...
      "highlight" : {
        "preview_html" : [ "<<tag1>p</tag1> class=\"text\">TOP STORIES</<tag1>p</tag1>><<tag1>p</tag1> class=\"text\">Middle East</<tag1>p</tag1>><<tag1>p</tag1> class=\"text\">Syria: Developments in Syria are main story in Middle East</<tag1>p</tag1>>" ]
      }

...
```

2. Using the `html` encoder:

The existing HTML syntax is escaped by elasticsearch, which breaks things, i.e. `<p>` -> `&lt;<tag1>p</tag1>&gt;`:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-type: application/json' "http://localhost:7200/myindex/_search?pretty" -d '
{
  "query": { "match": { "preview_html": "p" } },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags" : ["<tag1>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</tag1>"],
    "encoder": "html",
    "fields": {
      "preview_html" : {}
    }
  },
  "from" : 22, "size" : 1
}'

GIVES:
...
      "highlight" : {
        "preview_html" : [ "&lt;<tag1>p</tag1> class=&quot;text&quot;&gt;TOP STORIES&lt;&#x2F;<tag1>p</tag1>&gt;&lt;<tag1>p</tag1> class=&quot;text&quot;&gt;Middle East&lt;&#x2F;<tag1>p</tag1>&gt;&lt;<tag1>p</tag1> class=&quot;text&quot;&gt;Syria: Developments in Syria are main story in Middle East&lt;&#x2F;<tag1>p</tag1>&gt;" ]
        }
      }

...
```

Comment: And you want to have it like `<tag1><p></tag1>`?

Comment: Also, can you provide the mapping for `preview_html` field?

Comment: @AndreiStefan: I have updated the question text to answer your two questions.

Comment: I'm sorry but you didn't answer the questions. `type: string` is the only detail for that field? You don't have analyzers defined or similar? Also, you say _not to highlight any HTML markup which has matched the search_ but in the example you are highlighting html tags (`<p><mark>p</mark></p>`), so which one is it?

Comment: 1. Yes, "type: string" is the only mapping instruction I have given ES for that column. Any analyzers will be the default ones. 2. The example is showing that the "p" in the text is highlighted with "<mark>", but the "p" in the HTML tag name <p> is not highlighted (compare to the first example query shown in full in the question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use the [html_strip char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html) while analyzing `preview_html` field.
This would ensure that while matches would not occur on html markup and hence highlighting would ignore it to as shown in the example below.

Example:

```
put test
{
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
               "my_html": {
                  "type": "html_strip"
               }
            },
            "analyzer": {
               "my_html": {
                  "tokenizer": "standard",
                  "char_filter": [
                     "my_html"
                  ],
                  "type": "custom"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

put test/test/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
      "preview_html": {
         "type": "string",
         "analyzer": "my_html",
         "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
   }
}

put test/test/1
{
    "preview_html": "<p> p </p>"
}

post test/test/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "preview_html": "p"
      }
   },
   "highlight": {
      "fields": {
         "preview_html": {}
      }
   }
}
```

## Results

```
 "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "_source": {
               "preview_html": "<p> p </p>"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "preview_html": [
                  "<p> <em>p</em> </p>"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks ideal. I'll do some testing and see if I can get this to work.

Comment: This will correctly only highlight the query matches, but when producing highlight fragments the html from the field source can be malformed. You can test this with a field that contains a lot of html text. As far as I know, the only way to get clean html highlighting is to store the extracted html text in a separate field and highlight that. Again, this is only a problem with highlighting a fragment. Highlighting the entire html field will not have a malformed html problem because all tags will be closed. This is an issue with elasticsearch and solr.

Comment: yes i agree it is a limitation. However in ES 5.4  if you wan't only a fragment probably [boundary-scanners](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#boundary-scanners) might help. I haven't tested it though.