# How to highlight html with only text results (without html tags) with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

As [Elasticsearch highlight matches in HTML without breaking syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586412/elasticsearch-highlight-matches-in-html-without-breaking-syntax) mentioned by @Rich, Elasticsearch may break the HTML tags if it isn't the whole document is shown.

And the result might be something like this:

```
    ...
  "highlight" : {
    "preview_html" : [ " class=\"text\">TOP STORIES" ]
  }

    ...
```

I've searched a lot of documents but didn't found a way to **save a copy of the plain text with only the HTML posted** to Elasticsearch.

I think the ideal way to do this, is to create a multi-fields and do some mapping things, but I can't find a way to affect the highlight results, which seemed like needed to be saved in the _source field.

If it can be down with some settings or mappings, the highlighted text can work right by re-indexing.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.